# Issue with .htacces rewrite rules and special characters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, special-characters

I use some rewrite rules to make readable urls for a forum. For example if you post a new topic with the subject title "Hey what do you think of this new car ?" i will make a link like this : `forum/cars/51-Hey-what-do-you-think-of-this-new-car-?` where 51 is the topic id.

in my .htaccess i use this rewrite rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9-a-z]+)/?$ forum/list_topics.php?key=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9-a-z]+)/([0-9]+)?$ forum/list_topics.php?key=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9-a-z]+)/([0-9]+)-(.*)/?$ forum/list_post.php?topic=$2 [L]
```

So this is working fine except when i post a subject title with these characters :  `+"*ç%&/()=?'^`

I use a php function to create the url which is :

```
$url_topic = str_replace(' ', '-', $url_topic); //replace space with -
$url_topic = urlencode($url_topic);//encode url
```

In this case, the value of $url_topic is : `34-%2B%22%2A%C3%A7%25%26%2F%28%29%3D%3F%27%5E` but when i click on it, i have the following error :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /forum/cars/34-+"*Ã§%&/()=?'^ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

What am i missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

URL-escaped strings are decoded in the string you implicitly compare against with a RewriteRule.  That means if you capture, they are already decoded!.

IMO, the best solution is to capture against %{THE_REQUEST} which is still URL-encoded the way the client did.  This requires 1 addl RewriteCond.

The 2nd option is to use the [B] flag to re-escape backreferences. I am not a fan of this one as the re-escaping is not really context aware of where the substitution is going.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation but could you add an example of the RewriteCond i have to make ? Otherwise i guess i'll simply remove special char from my php string..which is i think the best solution